# Unavailable language analyzers in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on analyzing text documents from different languages (mostly in European languages) using Elasticsearch, Anybody helps how to deal with the languages that don't have a dedicated analyzer such as Croatian, Polish, Slovenian and so on?

Comment: For Polish you have https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/v2.3.1/plugins/analysis-stempel

Comment: thanks @Andrei Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I was working on a text search application in Slovenian language with elasticsearch and python. Here you have a blog post [Efficient search in your local language](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/efficient-search-your-local-language-roman-ora%C4%8D) and a [sample code](https://github.com/romanorac/elastic_localized_search).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can get dictionary-based stemming with the `hunspell` token filter. See more details and tradeoffs at https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-dictionary-stemming-hunspell.